# Placing a float just under the text

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to place the chart (picture) higher, just under the text. However, even though I use: `\begin{figure}[ht]` the float stays at the bottom of the page. What should I do?[image]

Comment: Have you tried it without `figure`? Then the image is not floating ...

Comment: Do you mean to use only `\includegraphics` ?

Comment: I'll remember about that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `[ht]` would not allow the float to go at the bottom of the page. it looks to me like that is `h` position but the white space is in the image, as you have shown no code, it is hard to help

Comment: The behavior is not normal.  It probably comes from a publsher's document class designed specifically to prevent you from doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`float`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float/) package. This package provides the `H` placement modifier, which places the float at the location of the `\begin{figure}[H]` in the source code.

Comment: I tried this as well, but I'm still getting the same result